# How to fix iOS 13.x JavaScript prompt dialog keyboard bug (browser independent)

Tags: javascript, ios, prompt

Is it possible to fix iOS 13.x JavaScript prompt dialog keyboard bug? When you are writing in some input/textarea field and prompt dialog is called on enter/return key then writing in prompt dialog is not visible and keyboard seems to be frozen with no feedback. Bug is in Safari and Chrome too so it is iOS issue.

Bug demo (use device with iOS v13.x to see bug): https://jsfiddle.net/c2sk3tna/

```html
<h1>iOS 13.x JavaScript prompt dialog keyboard bug demo (browser independent)</h1>

Writing in prompt dialog does not work after hit enter/return (keyboard is frozen)<br>
<input type="text" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) prompt('Enter something')">
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use workaround with setTimeout() before calling prompt. But I think Apple should fix it.

Bug and fix demo (use device with iOS v13.x to see bug): https://jsfiddle.net/c2sk3tna/1

```html
<h1>iOS 13.x JavaScript prompt dialog keyboard bug demo (browser independent)</h1>

Writing in prompt dialog does not work after hit enter/return (keyboard is frozen):<br>
<input type="text" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) prompt('Enter something')"><br><br>

Writing in prompt dialog works fine after hit enter/return (used delay before prompt):<br>
<input type="text" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) setTimeout(function() { prompt('Enter something'); }, 100)">
```